# Is it possible to modify a function after passing it through another function?

Tags: javascript, wechat

For example, I am inside a development environment where I cannot access the global function directly. (I am developing a WeChat's weixin mini program plugin.)

Let's say the global variable App and Page are two functions respectively, and then I can pass them via a function let's call it `rprm(App, Page)`...

Then if I do

```
...
  var owxapp = App
  App = function(){
    ...
    return owxapp.apply(this, arguments)
  }
...
```

this won't work on the global App (frankly I think it is a sibling App, the plugin and the mini programs are probably really siblings instead of parent&child) because when I pass it via a function a new scope was generated.

Comment: Your question is particularly unclear, but I think that you are using `App` as a parameter name (`function rprm(App,Page){...}`) that shadows the global `App` variable.

Comment: Correct. The problem is, within rprm I cannot access the global App.

Comment: Then you just need to rename your parameters : `function rprm(_App,_Page){App=function(){_App();};}`. or access the global `App` variable through the `window` object if you are in a browser environment `window.App`.

Comment: The problem is since this is a plugin, App is redefined into `undefined` so `App = function() {...}` would throw an err.

Comment: Also there is no window object in mini programs.

Comment: @n00dl3 this is mini program https://walkthechat.com/wechat-mini-programs-simple-introduction/